# Lights on Xbox slim won't turn on and controller doesn't connect

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

So I recently fixed my xbox 360 slim because the fan was not working, I fixed it but then I got another problem. Now my xbox can turn on but the front lights don't light up and I cant connect my controllers anymore. Every time I turn it on the main dashboard shows but I can't connect my controllers. Any advice or help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controller turns on. On the back of the controller press the button with the 3 arrows (by RB and LB) and hold and on your xbox click the same button on the bottom right left to the USB ports.
Is your xbox curved or not?